# how to pass a run time variable in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

```
set serverout on
declare
first_num number(8):=&num;
second_num number(8):=&num1;
result number(8);
begin
result:=(first_num/second_num+second_num);
dbms_output.put_line('the resultant value is:'||result);
end;
```

I want to pass the variable at run time,while i running this program in oracle apex 4.1 i got the below error message

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 22:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new not null continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
date
pile
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&` substitution is a feature of the sqlplus client, not PL/SQL itself. So you question is specific to this "Oracle Apex" client you are using (never heard of it sorry). My understanding is some other GUI clients also support the `&` substitution. I just use sqlplus myself.

The `&num` is not valid PL/SQL. But by default sqlplus would substitute it for the corresponding value before passing the code to the server for parsing/executiuon. If you are actually developing programs then you need to look at bind variables for you language/framework. Sorry I don't have a proper solution for you, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about launching a sqlplus session from within APEX to the backend server to execute, then your script looks fine.  But I will change your variable to &1 and &2 instead of &num and &num1 in this case and give this a try.

But if you are trying to execute this block of code directly in APEX, then Sodved is correct that you will need to look for first labeling your variable as :num and :num1 respectively and then the calling module must bind the variable to it before you can execute it.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
first_num number(8):=&num;
second_num number(8):=&num1;
```

write

```
first_num number(8):=:num;
second_num number(8):=:num1;
```

It works in apex.